# What binary architectures should be cross-compiled when building Mac OS X packages?

Tags: macos, x86, cross-compiling

Currently, Apple's native binaries and libraries are distributed as fat files, with support for both i386 and x86_64 architectures. The SDK (Xcode 4.4 w/ command line tools) doesn't support cross-compiling powerpc binaries any more, so they can be safely ignored I think, but there doesn't seem to be any specific guidelines or recommendations about which Intel architectures to support.

So, when compiling code for distribution on OS X, do people still cross-compile for the i386 architecture? Or are x86_64 binaries the only architecture worth bothering with nowadays?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266902/differences-between-compiling-for-i386-vs-x86-64-in-xcode

Comment: Thanks, I missed that question, although it's more relevant to how one should write the code in the first place, rather than configure a build that already works on both architectures. Building twice, finding binaries and turning them into universal fat files with `lipo` isn't much fun, but seems to be the only way to build some universal binaries, especially those which auto-tune themselves, like ATLAS.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I do believe that they are somewhat, if not entirely the same.

Comment: Somewhat, yes, but not entirely. I understand why the need for cross-compiling different architectures, so I'm not asking about the differences between the formats, but whether I should compile i386 binaries in the first place, when x86_64 works fine, at least on my Mac Pro 2010. Perhaps a better question: can i386-only, Intel-based Macs run Mountain Lion? I guess they can, but how long ago were they made, and what were they? i.e. should I bother supporting them?